# I have a problem with pygame blit image. Image doesn't get my wanted position and direction. How can I solve?

Tags: python, pygame

Sorry For Bad English

by.x is my sprite x position,
by.y is my sprite y position

I want to image gets my sprite's position and gets direction to target pos.
I write this code, but it isn't like my wanted.

```
main_skill_image.blit(pygame.transform.rotate(main_skill_image,math.atan2(target_pos[1]-by.y,target_pos[0]-by.x)/math.pi*180 + 180),(by.x,by.y))
```

Comment: You want your image to rotate towards the target position?

Comment: Yes, I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162302/pygame-point-image-towards-mouse) You could do something like this:

```
angle = 360-math.atan2(pos[1]-by.x,pos[0]-by.y)*180/math.pi
mai_skill_image= pygame.transform.rotate(main_skill_image,angle)
```

Haven't tested it, if it doesn't work, ill test it and fix it.