# How do I move to the mouse pointer and point towards it at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame2

I am quite new to Pygame 2 (actually python in general), and I wanted to make a little game for school. I used the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162302/pygame-point-image-towards-mouse), but I can't get it to move towards the cursor when I press <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. I don't want it to move in the x/y axis...
This is the code btw

```
import sys, pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *
spaceship = ('spaceship.png')
mouse_c = ('cursor.png')
backg = ('background.jpg')
lazer = pygame.mixer.Sound("pew.WAV")
pygame.init()

display_width = 1280
display_height = 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Survival")

bk = pygame.image.load(backg).convert_alpha()
space_ship = pygame.image.load(spaceship).convert_alpha()
mousec = pygame.image.load(mouse_c).convert_alpha()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
Ammo = 20
Fuel = 200

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1 and Ammo <= 20:
        print("Pew")
        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(lazer)
    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 3 and Fuel <= 200:
        print("Boost")

screen.blit(bk, (0, 0))
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
angle = 270-math.atan2(pos[1]-(display_height/2),pos[0]-(display_width/2))*180/math.pi
rotimage = pygame.transform.rotate(space_ship,angle)
rect = rotimage.get_rect(center=((display_width/2),(display_height/2)))
screen.blit(rotimage,rect) #I need space_ship to rotate towards my cursor
screen.blit(mousec, (pos))
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)   #FPS
```

Running Pygame 2.0 on Python 3.8.
Any tips will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I rotate a sprite towards the mouse and move it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64805267/how-do-i-rotate-a-sprite-towards-the-mouse-and-move-it)

Comment: This is really useful, but I want it to move directly at the mouse cursor when you press {spacebar}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that "follows2 an target:

```py
def FollowMe(pops, fpos, step):
    # [...]
```

I recommend to compute the distance between the spaceship and the mouse and the unit direction vector from (`fpos`) to (`pops`).
The distance can be get by computing the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). Pygame provides [`distance_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to) for that. Th unit direction vector can be computed by dividing the direction vector by the distance or by normalizing ([`normalize()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.normalize)) the direction vector:

```py
target_vector       = pygame.math.Vector2(pops)
follower_vector     = pygame.math.Vector2(fpos)

distance = follower_vector.distance_to(target_vector)
direction_vector = target_vector - follower_vector
if distance > 0:
    direction_vector /= distance
```

Now you can define an exact `step_distance` and move to follower in direction of the sprite:

```py
if distance > 0:
    new_follower_vector = follower_vector + direction_vector * step_distance.
```

Define a `step` and ensure that the step distance is not grater than the step:

```py
step_distance = min(distance, step)
```

The maximum  step distance is

```py
max_step = distance - minimum_distance
```

Put it all together:

```py
def FollowMe(pops, fpos, step):
    target_vector       = pygame.math.Vector2(pops)
    follower_vector     = pygame.math.Vector2(fpos)
    new_follower_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(fpos)

    distance = follower_vector.distance_to(target_vector)
    if distance > 0:
        direction_vector    = (target_vector - follower_vector) / distance
        step_distance       = min(distance, step)
        new_follower_vector = follower_vector + direction_vector * step_distance

    return (new_follower_vector.x, new_follower_vector.y)
```

See also [How to make smooth movement in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087982/how-to-make-smooth-movement-in-pygame/64088747#64088747).

Use the function to move the space ship in the direction of the mouse and `pygame.key.get_pressed()` to move the ship when <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is pressed.  [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement:

```py
ship_pos = display_width // 2, display_height // 2

while True:
    # [...]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        ship_pos = FollowMe(pos, ship_pos, 3)
    angle = 270-math.atan2(pos[1]-ship_pos[1],pos[0]-ship_pos[0])*180/math.pi
    rotimage = pygame.transform.rotate(space_ship,angle)
    rect = rotimage.get_rect(center=ship_pos)
```

For the rotation of an image see [How to rotate an image(player) to the mouse direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603835/how-to-rotate-an-imageplayer-to-the-mouse-direction/58604116#58604116) and [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144)

See also [Rotate towards target or mouse](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_rotate_towards_target.md) respectivley [Move towards target](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_move_towards_target.md) and the answer to the question [How do I rotate a sprite towards the mouse and move it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64805267/how-do-i-rotate-a-sprite-towards-the-mouse-and-move-it)

---

Minimal example without any usage of external resources (sound and images):

[image]

```py
import sys, pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

def FollowMe(pops, fpos, step):
    target_vector       = pygame.math.Vector2(pops)
    follower_vector     = pygame.math.Vector2(fpos)
    new_follower_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(fpos)

    distance = follower_vector.distance_to(target_vector)
    if distance > 0:
        direction_vector    = (target_vector - follower_vector) / distance
        step_distance       = min(distance, step)
        new_follower_vector = follower_vector + direction_vector * step_distance

    return (new_follower_vector.x, new_follower_vector.y) 

display_width = 1280
display_height = 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Survival")
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

bk = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
space_ship = pygame.Surface((20, 50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
space_ship.fill((0, 255, 0)) 
mousec = pygame.Surface((20, 20), pygame.SRCALPHA)
mousec.fill((255, 0, 0)) 

ship_pos = display_width // 2, display_height // 2

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        ship_pos = FollowMe(pos, ship_pos, 3)
    angle = 270-math.atan2(pos[1]-ship_pos[1],pos[0]-ship_pos[0])*180/math.pi
    rotimage = pygame.transform.rotate(space_ship,angle)
    rect = rotimage.get_rect(center=ship_pos)
    
    screen.blit(bk, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(rotimage,rect)
    screen.blit(mousec, pos)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I want it to move if you press the spacebar, so which of these parts would I put an If statement?

Comment: @DarkSlayer3202 It is a bad style to change the question. Anyway, I've changed the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I forgot that I needed that part :/   Thanks anyways!